# Where can I find design recommendations for electrical (load) distribution in a residential home?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

This question is in regard to USA standards and practices, and of particular interest any points specific to locations in southern Florida, including coastal areas.

Either in new construction or existing home renovation is there a source of reference material on the design of the wiring, especially distribution and control of the loads not thought of in decades past?   In particular EV charging circuits, on site power generation (solar, fuel cell, backup generators, battery storage, etc.), smart control and monitoring of power usage, and extensibility (future home additions, new technologies and the like).

If I were having a new home built what should be specified to achieve a safe, adaptable, expandable system?   Better yet, with the new tax credits for "upgrading" hme power distribution, what is reasonable to implement in an existing home?

Links or titles of reference materials would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.nfpa.org/codes-and-standards/all-codes-and-standards/list-of-codes-and-standards/detail?code=70

Comment: Conduit for cat-5 to *every* room. Conduit to the garage big enough to pull +50 amps. Empty conduit run from the load center to the attic for solar. Planing for things that don't exist yet isn't a thing. Planning for things you know will *change* is though, i.e., conduit for cat-[7]. If anything, power consumption will be less and less, but it sure is convenient when there's a quad outlet feed by #12 every six feet.

Comment: Communications/network conduits to the center of the ceiling in any major room. Good wireless is built on wires or fibers to wireless access points that are not blocked by walls from the wireless devices. Mid-ceiling is a really good place for that.